# Where did the GXT 2.2.5 Demo Explorer site go?

Tags: extjs, gxt

Sencha released a new version of [GXT](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/). They have a nice [Demo Explorer](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3aoverview) site where you can see example and see the code.
However, we are still using the previous version 2.2.5 and the Demo Explorer site is now running on the new version 3.

Is the previous Version of the Demo explorer still out there somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 2.x explorer was moved to http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/.

Comment: ingorance -> google -> stack -> answer. the flow of my life

Comment: Sometime in the last few weeks, this link has begun redirecting to the GXT 4.0 demo explorer. It looks like the 2.x explorer is again no longer available on Sencha's website.

Comment: I'll see if we can get that fixed.

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5.zip --> the product artifact
http://gxt-rtl.googlecode.com/git/war/examples.html --> gxt2.2.5 example

Comment: Thanks! the examples link doesn't work, but I downloaded the zip from your link and deployed the gxt-2.2.5/samples/samples.war. It is the demo explorer working perfectly.